# Pygame, distutils and fonts

Tags: python, pygame, distutils

I want to use a font file in my application (pygame requires an exact path to the font file) and I also want to package this application using distutils. The package must work independently of the platform. How to edit setup.py file to achieve this? I use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you right; you want to use a font, but avoid Sysfont right?

What I do in that case is to download a font a write this to my program:

```
fontSize = 15
workdir = os.getcwd()
path_to_font = os.path.join(workdir, 'your-font.ttf')
myFont = pygame.font.Font(path_to_font, fontSize)
```

This however implies that the font you downloaded is in your work directory

You can read more about it here: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font